# Unable to bind bootstrap model text field with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that is displayed when a button is clicked. Although I was able to bind all the values in the view, I am not able to bind the modal properties with knockout.

Here is my modal code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="clientName">Client Name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
            <input name="clientName" class="form-control" required id="clientName" data-bind="textInput: clientName">
      </div>                          
  </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
self.clientName = ko.observable();
self.onAddNewClient = function () {
       $("#clientProperties").modal({ backdrop: "static" });
  };
self.onSaveClientProperties = function () {
        var item=self.clientName();

 };
```

The modal shows up just fine but when I enter a value in the text field and save it, the 'clientName' variable is undefined instead having the value that was entered. 'onSaveClientProperties' is a function that runs when a button is clicked on the modal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you setup your modal, but I wrote a plunker that seems to do what you want:
[binding input in modal](https://jsfiddle.net/matiasm/3v3c7hkf/25/)

```
<body>


  <div id="clientProperties" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Client</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input name="clientName" class="form-control" required id="clientName" data-bind="textInput: clientName">
              <a href="#" data-bind="click: onSaveClientProperties" >save</a>
            </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clientProperties"> Add new Client</a>
```

Comment: I replaced my whole modal with your code just to check and i still get the clientName as undefined. I thought it may be a bindings issue but it calls the onSaveClienProperties function correctly so i guess it's not the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue. I created my project using VS 2015 ASP.NET single page template and it used the Knockout-2.3.0.debug.js. First of all, that resource is not being loaded as its not included in the default knockout bundle so i did that and it still didn't work. I updated my knockout to Knockout3.4.2 and voila it worked.

Not sure why VS2015 hasn't updated to the newest version of the Knockout.